# Is it possible to use ngFor to display multiple component selector tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular-cli

I have a question in angular 2.
so i am able to use ngFor to display {{data}} tags from a local json and display the data.

However i was wondering if theres a way to render component selector tags that are stored in a json and display them within an ng for. for example,
 I have this json **component.ts** in my file: (See comments for explanation about the issue)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
widgets;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.widgets = [
{
  "widgetcode": "<app-analytics-widget></app-club-chooser>" //Existing component selector tag within the angular cli system
},
{
  "widgetcode": "<app-club-chooser></app-club-chooser>" //Existing component selector tag within the angular cli system
},
{
  "widgetcode": "<app-account-widget></app-account-widget>" //Existing component selector tag within the angular cli system
}



    ]
  }

}
```

my component.html file:

```
    <div class="DahsboardWrapper">

<!-- DashBoard Ges here -->

<!-- widget elements go here -->
<div class="DashoardHeaderClass" id="dashboard">
Dashboard Loaded
<div class="WidgetAreaWrapper">
<div class="widgets" *ngFor="let widget of widgets">


 <!-- {{widget.widgetcode}}  Not working atm..-->
<!-- this is displayng just plain text -->
</div>

<!-- This is working --> 
<app-analytics-widget></app-analytics-widget>
<app-club-chooser></app-club-chooser>
<app-account-widget></app-account-widget>

</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions maybe theres a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot go from selector. That wouldn't work in production with Ahead of Time (AoT) compiler anyway, because the compiler runs at build time, and it is what matches selectors to components and directives.

If you have a limited set of tags in mind, you can use [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). Each of the components you support would be one of the `switch` `case`s, and you choose which one to display by some string property in your JSON. The entire `[ngSwitch]` would be the `ngFor` item.

If you need to support more complex scenarios, and you are using Angular 4, you can use [ngComponentOutlet'](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet). This still required a Type (importing the class) not a selector.

Finally, also Angular 4, for dynamically loading components in general, you can pick which way makes most sense to you by the many ways supported in this library https://github.com/apoterenko/ngx-dynamic-template.

Comment: Thanks for your help. ngSwitch works liek a charm. for anyone looking to use this in the futur heres a good tutroail about it. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/